# Zermelo-Fraenkel versus Constructive-Zermelo-Fraenkel

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics

Let's suppose that a particular theorem cannot be proved in ZF (for example, because I have a counterexample in ZF).
Is it possible that the theorem hold in CZF?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, a proof in CZF would also work in ZF, so if ZF proves it false, CZF isn't going to prove it true.

Comment: Every axiom of CZF is provable in ZF, so every theorem of CZF is a theorem of ZF.

Comment: @MarkSaving where can I find a reference of the fact that every axiom of CZF is provable in ZF?